# Create a Maven project with hibernate

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven

I need to create a maven project, which also has hibernate. How do i write the maven create project command.

The IDE i'm using is Eclipse.

Comment: Can't you just add hibernate dipendence to the POM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an appropriate [maven archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) E.g.:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
                   -DgroupId=com.my-company.my-project \
                   -DartifactId=my-project-domain \
                   -DpackageName=com.company.project.domain \
                   -DarchetypeGroupId=com.rfc.maven.archetypes \
                   -DarchetypeArtifactId=jpa-maven-archetype  \
                   -DremoteRepositories=http://maven.rodcoffin.com/repo \
                   -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0
```

You can find some Hibernate archetypes here http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List
or use google

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking what archetype would be best to use from the command line, then the below will give you a nice list to choose from:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

However, you say you're using Eclipse - if so, take advantage of the Maven integration and you'll be offered a similar choice when creating the project (basically just a nice GUI around archetype:generate and friends)